# youtube object template not showing when links added from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, youtube-api

I have stored an object template in a variable and then I'm adding the video links via jQuery. I'm doing this because eventually the links will be added into the object template via ajax.

However, the video does not show up. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The sample code is in action here: http://jsbin.com/axifil

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var obj_template = '<object width="260" height="140">' +   
                          '<param name="movie" value=""></param>' +  
                          '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>' +  
                          '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>' +  
                          '<embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="260" height="140"></embed>' +  
                          '</object>'; 
  var flash_obj = obj_template;
  var video = $('.video');
  $(flash_obj).find('object param[name="movie"]').attr('value', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded');
  $(flash_obj).find('object embed').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded');
  alert(flash_obj);
  $('.video_content').html(flash_obj);
  $('.test').html('this shows');
  });
</script>
<div id="top_row_center" class="video">
  <p class="video_content"></p>
  <p class="test"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first add `object` to div `video_content` then change `movie` and `src`
because before you'r changing the string that does not exsite on document;

```
  $('.video_content').html(obj_template );
  var flash_obj = $('.video_content object');
  var video = $('.video');
  $(flash_obj).find('param[name="movie"]').attr('value', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded');
  $(flash_obj).find('embed').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?version=3&feature=player_embedded');
  console.log(flash_obj);
  $('.test').html('this shows');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V2nJG/1/